# c() malfunction?

Tags: r

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, and would appreciate any assistance.

Trying to make a new variable named "control" and coding it 1 when the row variable is equal to these numbers, and 0 when it is not.

```
data$control= ifelse (data$row==c(146, 297, 313, 171, 262, 233, 292, 304, 264, 228, 279,      
281, 290, 277, 152, 161, 250, 263, 245,  83,  67, 101,  98, 251, 148, 155, 322, 265, 
159, 271, 278, 289, 274, 282, 158, 196, 154, 260, 163, 307, 272, 299, 300, 273, 167, 
286, 149, 316, 147, 162, 178), 1, 0)
```

It makes a new variable named "control" but only codes it as 1 for row=149 and row=264.  I really cannot figure this out.

Thanks for the help, 
Chris

Comment: what part of c(146, 297, 313, 171, 262, 233, 292, 304, 264, 228, 279,      
281, 290, 277, 152, 161, 250, 263, 245,  83,  67, 101,  98, 251, 148, 155, 322, 265, 
159, 271, 278, 289, 274, 282, 158, 196, 154, 260, 163, 307, 272, 299, 300, 273, 167, 
286, 149, 316, 147, 162, 178) is a malfunction? You should retitle the q to match it

Comment: Just a general troubleshooting tip: always break down your arguments to make sure they're doing what you think you're doing! Do `data$row==c(146,....)` and you'll know right away it's not what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean to use `%in%` rather than `==`:

```
data$control= ifelse (data$row %in% c(146, 297, 313, 171, 262, 233, 292, 304, 264, 228, 279, 281, 290, 277, 152, 161, 250, 263, 245, 83, 67, 101, 98, 251, 148, 155, 322, 265, 159, 271, 278, 289, 274, 282, 158, 196, 154, 260, 163, 307, 272, 299, 300, 273, 167, 286, 149, 316, 147, 162, 178), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Instead of `ifelse(logical_expression, 1, 0)`, one could use `as.integer(logical_expression)`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: or `logical_expression+0` :)